# Automating Self Sign Certificate IIS7 (possibly with appcmd)

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, self-signed, build-script

I currently have a rake script which compiles, packages and deploys an ASP MVC web project. Currently I am tearing down and setting up IIS every time the build script is run, however I am now looking at adding some SSL additions so will want to deploy the IIS sites with a self signed certificate and set up the bindings to allow for HTTPS.

After having a quick look around the internet looks like there is no simple solution, but just wanted to double check, as ideally I would like to just piggy back on appcmd through the command line and send that some info on what to do, but am open to using another tool providing I can run it through the command line to do the work needed

Any info related to the above would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using SelfSSL7, which does everything I need. It allows you to give it the site name in IIS and it will create the certificate, also can mark it as trusted, although I am not sure if this only works for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I solve this situation by this way. I create in IIS Website, where exists bindings, self-sign certificate is generated and associated etc. (full setting website). Path to website directory is for example C:\Website. If you used Visual Studio 2012, you can do (after first create) "Publish" on website project. I publish project to file system to directory  C:\Website (website directory). All works fine.

Best regards,
 Peter